# Storing data in cache in an Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, angular-http, wordpress-rest-api

I am using an external Wordpress Rest API as content for my Ionic app.

This provides up to 500 pages feeding from my Wordpress site. If a user doesn't have internet access when accessing my app. Is there a way I can populate all the content in the Apps cache before I do my App build so there will be some content to view for every page.

Then perhaps later when they get internet access back that page can be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to store client-side and persistent data, you can't use the [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory), which just caches the data for the current session.

You can save data in [localStorage](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/saving-data-with-ionicframework/).

Make something like this:

**Factory**

```
.factory('Content', ['$http', Content])

function Content($http) {

     function getcontent(callback, url) {
        var articles = [];
        var article = {};
        $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
            if (response.content[0].length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.content[0].length; i++) {
                    article = {
                        title:response.content[0][i].title,  
                        subtitle:response.content[0][i].subtitle
                    }
                    articles.push(article); 
                }
            } else {
                //      
            }
        }).error(function() {
            //        
        }).then(function() {
            callback(articles);
        });;
    }
    return {
        getcontent: getcontent
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('ContentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', 'Content', '$localStorage',
    function($scope, $http, $timeout, Content, $localStorage) {

        $scope.showContent = function() {

                var url = WordPressUrl;
                $timeout(function() {
                    Content.getcontent(function(data) {
                        $scope.getcontent = data;
                        var contentList = [];
                        data.forEach(function(localy) {
                            var oneArticle = {
                                title: localy.title,
                                subtitle: localy.subtitle
                            }
                            contentList.push(oneArticle);
                        });
                        window.localStorage.setItem("ContentLocaly", JSON.stringify(contentList));
                        // $localStorage.message = localStorage["ContentLocaly"];
                    }, url);
                }, 1000);
        }

          //  $scope.showContent();

    }
])
```

Then you can use it in other controllers.

```
        $scope.LocalyFeed = function() {
            $scope.Wordpress = JSON.parse(localStorage["ContentLocaly"]);
            console.log($scope.Wordpress);
        //  return $scope.Wordpress;
        };
```

> For checking internet connection you can make something like this.

**Factory**

```
.factory('checkInternet', function() {
    return function checkInternet() {
        var haveInternet= true;
        if (window.cordova) {
            if (window.Connection) {
                if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
                    haveInternet= false;
                }
            }
        }
        return haveInternet;
    };
})
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','checkInternet',
    function($scope, $http, checkInternet) {

        $scope.showSomething = function() {
        var haveInternet= checkInternet();
       if (haveInternet== true) {
        // do something
       } else {
        // do something else   
        }

        }
 }
])
```

Comment: Would I have to go into each of the 500 pages to "generate" the cache or is automatically created or populated somehow?

Comment: I've updated the answer. You will pull data (array) from API, store it in localStorage and then use it in app when there is no Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service first

// Set up the cache ‘myCache’

```
 myApp.factory('myCache', function($cacheFactory) {
      return $cacheFactory('myData');
});
```

//in controller

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myCache',

function ($scope, myCache) {
  var cache = myCache.get('myData');

  if (cache) { // If there’s something in the cache, use it!
    $scope.variable = cache;
  }
  else { // Otherwise, let’s generate a new instance
    myCache.put(‘myData’, 'This is cached data!');
    $scope.variable = myCache.get('myData');
  }
}

]);
```